# tkinter .replace() function not doing anything in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

So I recently made a simple mp3 player with Tkinter and pygame in python. And when I added the function to import a song, thanks to Codemy.com, I was able to do so but it would make the title of the song the entire directory: "C:/User/Desktop/song title" instead of just the song title.

I used the .replace() function and it just didn't work.

here is the code:

```
def AddSong():
    Music_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='Audio/', title="Choose A Song", filetypes=(("mp3 Files", "*.mp3"), ))
    Music = Music_name.replace("C:/gui/Audio/", "")
    CustomMusic.insert(END, Music)
```

Comment: If the directory is `C:/User/Desktop/song title`, then `replace("C:/gui/Audio/", "")` won't do anything because `"C:/gui/Audio/"` is not a substring of `"C:/User/Desktop/song title"`

Comment: how would I change the directory and just get the song name if It was in any directory? Like more than just desktop, documents, etc?

Comment: Consider using `pathlib` instead of doing string operations on file paths. It is easier, more maintainable, and is likely to give more useful error messages.

Comment: @TechoWinMC, with `pathlib` you can do `Music = pathlib.Path(Music_name).name` to get the name - it'll parse the path automatically

Comment: @ForceBru oh thanks so much! My python file is in a separate folder called MusicPlayer, and the Songs are in a folder in musicplayer called Audio. This helps a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it with the help of ForceBRU,
I was told to use pathlib instead because it's more stable and it works perfectly.
After I converted to.exe, I made some changes but overall it's flawless.

```
def AddSong():
    Music_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='Audio/', title="Choose A Song", filetypes=(("mp3 Files", "*.mp3"), ))
    Music = pathlib.Path(Music_name).name # - Here is the code your looking for
    CustomMusic.insert(END, Music)
```